# model.find({}).populate('place').populate('location') does not return place and location

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have document with the following structure on MongoDb,

[image]

I am using Mongoose **`version ^4.8.1`** with my node application. I have created 3 schema models for the above document which are as follows,

**Event.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String        
    },
    end_time: {
        type: Date      
    },
    start_time: {
        type: Date      
    },
    name: {
        type: String    
    },
    place: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'place'
    }
});
eventSchema.index({name: 'text'},{'place.location.country':"text"});
var Event = mongoose.model('events', eventSchema);
module.exports= Event;
```

**Place.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String    
    },
    location: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'location'
    }
});

var Place = mongoose.model('place', placeSchema);
module.exports= Place;
```

**Location.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: {
        type: String        
    },
    latitude: {
        type: String        
    },
    country: {
        type: String        
    },
    located_in: {
        type: String        
    },
    state: {
        type: String        
    },
    street: {
        type: String        
    },
    zip: {
        type: String        
    },


});
var Location = mongoose.model('location', locationSchema);
module.exports= Location;
```

Common handler to access /query database,

**dbHandler.js**

```
querandpoplulate : function(model,condition,options)
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            options = options||{};
            console.log("model is" + model);
            model.find({}).populate('place').populate('location').exec(function(error, data) {
                if (error)
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);        
               console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
            })
        })

    }
```

Here is how i query,

```
dbHelper.querandpoplulate(mongoose.model('events'), {$text: {$search: searchString},'place.location.country': countryString},function(error,data){
                            callback(data);       
});
```

Question: it does not return the result set with the place and location , it returns null in place field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your documents are saved as `embedded documents`, but not as `referenced documents`.

To fetch such documents, you don't need to do any `population`. Simple `find` query  should work for you.

Try this:

```
model.find({}).exec(function(error, data) {
    if (error)
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);        
   console.log(data);
    resolve(data);
})
```

As you are not saving the `data` in the `mongoDB` but only retrieving it. you need to define the `schema` that matches with the `document` structure.

As discussed with you, i think you need to change the `Schema`, and combine all 3 `schemas` in one file (**Event.js**).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: {
        type: String        
    },
    //add other fields here 
});

var placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String    
    },
    location: locationSchema
});

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String        
    },
    //add other fields here too
    place: placeSchema
});
eventSchema.index({name: 'text'},{'place.location.country':"text"});
var Event = mongoose.model('events', eventSchema);
module.exports= Event;
```

Comment: Still it returns place:null

Comment: this is the result { _id: 5890b47f6166c457ffdee3d3,
    end_time: 2016-11-11T00:00:00.000Z,
    name: 'Energía Tour Europa - Milán',
    place: null,
    start_time: 2016-11-10T19:00:00.000Z,
    id: '631789367000065' }

Comment: Your index `place.location.country':"text"` seems wrong, as place is just an objectId in that schema, and place.location will be undefined. I don't know if this will cause an issue but everything else looks fine

Comment: did you check the document structure? is it fine?

Comment: yes, i looked at the code, Everything looks fine. Also, can you show me how your document is stored (or looks) in mongoDb

Comment: one more thing, are you sure a valid ObjectId is placed in place and location field in the document?

Comment: i have attached the image, thats how it is stored

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134974/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-and-sajeetharan).